# Laravel + Nginx. Session is accessed randomly

Tags: session, nginx, laravel-5

We have an app build in laravel and we are trying to switch from apache to nginx but when we enable the nginx, the users are getting logged into random users account on every refresh.

For example,

I am logged in as USER1, refresh the page and now I am in USER2 account, USER3 account randomly.

We are using redis as session driver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing the same problem. This happens because Nginx cached both static and dynamic content of the website. What you have to do is just disable the dynamic caching and everything will work normally.

We used the Engintron plugin for WHM so I can tell you the configuration for that.

Edit `common_http.conf` file and set this value to 1

`set $CACHE_BYPASS_FOR_DYNAMIC 1;`